# Quiero convertir un string en un array separado por 4 caracteres en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de convertir un string de 16 digitos a un array separado por cada 4 digitos.

De esto

```
var string = "1234567812345678"
```

A esto

```
var array = ["1234, 5678, 1234, 5678"]
```

o en su defecto, agregar un espacio cada 4 caracteres al ser insertado en el html

`<p>1234 5678 1234 5678</p>`

Comment: Eso son 8 dígitos, no 16.  Pon lo que has intentado para que podamos corregirte, gracias.

Comment: es un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer, seria lo mismo que poner ese mimo ejemplo pero x 2 

var string = "1234567812345678"
var array = ["1234, 5678, 1234, 5678"]

Comment: Revisa la siguiente documentacion https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Debes mostrar lo que estas intentando para que podamos ayudarte. Exponer un problema sin mostrar lo que has hecho para solucionarlo está mal visto por aquí, pues no se hacen tareas o código desde cero, lo siento. Pon el código que estás intentando hacer funcionar para su corrección, gracias. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask], [tour] y [example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si siempre son 16 caracteres, otro modo de hacerlo es

```js
var string = "1234567812345678";
var resultado = [string.slice(0,4), string.slice(4,8),string.slice(8,12),string.slice(12,16)];

console.log(resultado);

console.log(resultado.join(" ")); //un unico string separador por espacio
```

Pero más corto seria:

```js
var string = "1234567812345678";
var resultado = `${string.slice(0,4)} ${string.slice(4,8)} ${string.slice(8,12)} ${string.slice(12,16)}`;

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Tambien me gusta mucho este, es mas practico para la finalidad que busco, muchas gracias por el aporte :)

Comment: *Pero más corto seria*... ¿Qué tal fuesen más caracteres? ¿No crees que el código sería más **extenso**? Y no lo digo solo por el autor, sino por los demás que tengan algún problema **similar** y no solo con 16 caracteres :)

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Si fuesen más caracteres seria otra pregunta, tal como el OP dice son 16 siempre, este dato es parte de pregunta. Además yo aclaro en mi respuesta para los demás que tengan una pregunta similar, que la respuesta considera 16 caracteres. Por último, yo podría argumentar lo mismo de su respuesta ¿Y si quisiera separar en 3 y no en 4?

Comment: Simplemente cambiar `cadena.match(/.{1,4}/g`) a `cadena.match(/.{1,3}/g)`, sería mucho más fácil hacer eso que tener un código más largo, lo digo más que nada por el nivel de complejidad. Tu código está bien, solamente te doy mi observación.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Por supuesto, y en mi caso también habría que cambiar el código. Yo decidí presentar un modo alternativo al suyo, porque intuí que podría servirle al OP de esta manera y al parecer estaba en lo correcto

Answer (score 9):

Lo que hice fue utilizar el método `match` para separar cada 4 caracteres de tu cadena.

```js
var cadena = "1234567812345678";
var arreglo = cadena.match(/.{1,4}/g);

console.log(arreglo);
```

Comment: Perfecto, ya puedo continuar con mi codigo.

Voy a buscar documentacion, no sabia que se podia usar de esa manera, muchas gracias :)

Comment: A usted. Recuerda ver la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) de este método para más información, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Si ya sabes que son 16 caracteres, porque te complicas, si podemos usar nuestro for de confianza y que recorra de 4 en 4, un codigo simple y facil de aprender

```js
const str = "1234567812345678"
const datos = []
for (let i = 0; i<= str.length - 1; i=i+4){
  datos.push(str.substring(i,i+4))

}
console.log(datos)
```