# Seleccionar de un string una cadena numerica y seprarla por un separador con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este string de ejemplo `Hola 12345678` y quisiera separarlo por tomando como regla para el `split` los espacios en blanco entre ellos para luego verificar si contiene una cadena númerica: En el caso que contenga una cadena númerica me gustaría separar esta cadena numerica cada `4 digitos` por un seprardor **`"-"`**. Implemente esta linea de código pero lo único que me hace es quitarme el espaciado en el string y me devuelve el string unido.

Esta es la línea de codigo:

```
let value = "Hola 12345678"; 
let countForSeparator = 4;
let separator = "-";  

let arr = value.split(' ').map( (x,i) => isNumber(Number(i)) &&  (i > 0 && i % countForSeparator == 0) ? separator + x : x ).join('') ;
```

Que estaré omitiendo en mi línea de código? Alguna idea que puedan aportar?

```
**UPADTE**
```

Limpie un poco más el codigo con esta línea:

```
let arr = value.split(' ').filter( x => (x.match(/[0-9]/g) ?? []).map((a,i) => (i > 0 && i % countForSeparator == 0) ? separator + a : a ).join('')) ;
```

Pero esta vez me devuelve solamente el la cadena de numeros pero sin poner los speradores

**UPDATE 2**

sustitui el `filter` por un `map` y obtengo dos dos `array de sting` uno con un espacio en blanco y otro con mis numeros separados como quiero. Pero no me muestra el resultado final como `"Hola 1234-5678"` como quisiera que pudiera estar faltandome? Este es el codigo nuevo

```
let arr = value.split(' ').map( x => (x.match(/[0-9]/g) ?? []).map((a,i) => (i > 0 && i % countForSeparator == 0) ? separator + a : a ).join('')) ;
```

Comment: Qué vendría a ser `isNumber` y `countForSeparator`?

Comment: comprobar si es numerico, pero voy a poner una actualizacion

Comment: countSeparator es la cantidad de digitos que debe tomar por cada separaciones del "-"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podemos resolverlo de una manera más sencilla.

---

Tengamos pensado lo siguiente:

- Debemos ingresar a los elementos del array devuelto por el `split()`, esto lo podemos hacer con `map()`.
- En cada uno de los elementos, verificamos (con una expresión regular) qué elemento contiene **sólo números** (del `0` al `9`).
- Si esto se cumple, entonces a ese elemento lo separamos en grupo de 4 con otra expresión regular (extraída de [**una de mis respuestas**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/557257/quiero-convertir-un-string-en-un-array-separado-por-4-caracteres-en-javascript/557258#557258)), si no cumple, devolvemos el elemento original (que serían letras).
- A cada grupo de 4 lo unimos con guiones (ya que es lo que necesitas).
- Y por último, volvemos a unir los elementos del array devuelto por el `split()` inicial (las letras y los números separados por guiones).

---

Una vez sabiendo esto, el código vendría a ser el siguiente:

```js
let arr = value.split(' ').map(x => { if (x.match(/\b[0-9]+\b/g)) { return x.match(/.{1,4}/g).join("-"); } return x; }).join(' ');
```

A simple vista el código sería difícil de entender, entonces separaré el código por partes (con una breve explicación) para que se logre entender mejor:

```
let arr = value
  .split(' ') // usamos al espacio como separador y tenemos => ["Hola-12345678"].
  .map(x => { // ingreso a cada uno de los elementos con map().
    // verificamos si el elemento contiene sólo números. Si contiene al menos una letra, lo ignoramos.
    if (x.match(/\b[0-9]+\b/g)) {
      // si cumple, a ese elemento lo separamos en grupo de 4, y cada grupo lo unimos con guiones.
      return x.match(/.{1,4}/g).join("-");
    }
    // de lo contrario retornamos el elemento original.
    return x;
  })
  // y por último juntamos los elementos.
  .join(' ');
```

**Código final:**

```js
let value = "Hola 12345678";
let arr = value.split(' ').map(x => { if (x.match(/\b[0-9]+\b/g)) { return x.match(/.{1,4}/g).join("-"); } return x; }).join(' ');
console.log(arr);
```

**Aquí el mismo código pero con más ejemplos:**

```js
let value1 = "Hola 12345678"; // letras y números.
let value2 = "12345678 12345678"; // números y espacios.
let value3 = "12345678910111213141"; // número extenso.
let value4 = "Hola 12345678 como 12345678 estas"; // números y letras consecutivamente.
let value5 = "H0L4 C0M0 3ST4S, 12345678 1234X5678"; // números y alfanuméricos.

function formato(value) {
  let arr = value.split(' ').map(x => { if (x.match(/\b[0-9]+\b/g)) { return x.match(/.{1,4}/g).join("-"); } return x; }).join(' ');
  return arr;
}

console.log(formato(value1));
console.log(formato(value2));
console.log(formato(value3));
console.log(formato(value4));
console.log(formato(value5));
```

Comment: Yo te votaría dos veces...